# Bluetooth issue with RasberryPi3

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi3, windows-iot-core-10

I have a RapsberryPi3 running windows iot. I am using the Rfcomm chat example to communicate with it using an android device over bluetooth. I managed to establish the connection successfully but after running the application for sometime(about 20-25 minutes), if I try to connect my android device to the Pi, the two devices are unable to connect. If I reboot the application, it connects again. I tried running the chat example on my desktop and have my phone connect to it and it works fine. Is this a know issue with RasberryPi?

Comment: Which scenario do you run on Raspberry Pi3, "Chat Client", "Foreground Chat Server" or "Background Chat Server"? What's "Status" info in UI when two devices can't connect?

Comment: there is a instability in Bluetooth driver in windows 10 iot core, even you use Ble GATT server or Rfcomm protocol after 30 minutes the Bluetooth  driver show instability behavior.